# ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection: Cannot modify association error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-many-through

What is the problem with this association?

My association looks like this:

```
class Quote < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :language_pairs
end

class LanguagePair < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :quote
    belongs_to :w_flow
    has_many :w_flow_steps, through: :w_flow
end

class WFlow < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :language_pairs
  has_many :w_flow_steps
end

class WFlowStep < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :w_flow
end
```

When i run

```
q=Quote.find(1)
q.language_pairs.create!(source_language:'French - EU', w_flow_id: 1)
```

I have following errors:

ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection: Cannot modify association 'LanguagePair#w_flow_steps' because the source reflection class 'WFlowStep' is associated to 'WFlow' via :has_many.

Comment: What do you want to do? create a `language_pairs` associated with the`Quote` with the `id` = 1?

Comment: That exception class name tho..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a `LanguagePair` a related with a particular `Quote`, first you need to get the `Quote` that you want to be associated:

```
q = Quote.find(1)
```

Then you pass that variable to the create method of your `LanguagePair`:

```
lp = LanguagePair.create!(quote: q, source_language:'French - EU', w_flow_id: 1)
```

And Rails will take care about the relations.

**Note**: you are using `create!` that will raise an exception if the record is invalid

Comment: yes that is one solution. Actaully I wanted to know the problem with  q.language_pairs.create!(source_language:'French - EU', w_flow_id: 1)

Comment: You want to create `language_pair` from the instance  `q`?

Comment: yes, can you explain why can't I do q.language_pairs.create!

Comment: You can't call `language_pairs.create!` because is not defined. Check this article: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: However, you can define a method in `Quote` that creates `LanguagePair`, is that reasonable in your case?